# Error when create Archive in XCode with Alamofire

Tags: xcode, swift

When ill try to create an Archive of my iOS App i am getting after install on an iPad the following error message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
 Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
 Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88C8DA30-F2C6-4311-B892-AB5571D5061F/mobilecap.app/assekuranz
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88C8DA30-F2C6-4311-B892-AB5571D5061F/assekuranz.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: mmap() error 1 at address=0x005D7000, size=0x00070000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88C8DA30-F2C6-4311-B892-AB5571D5061F/mobilecap.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
 Dyld Version: 353.6

 Binary Images:
 0x1fe43000 - 0x1fe66fff dyld armv7  <9ccfe28fdc823833b1927a781832605e> /usr/lib/dyld
```

When i am building the APP for the Device / Simulator, everything works fine.

Any ideas? Every help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved. I revoked my developer certificate and created a new .ipa file everything works fine.